# Using c++ I keep getting a redefinition of variable error that I cannot seem to avoid

Tags: c++, xcode

> **WHAT I want to code to do**

The code should accept to int values from the user, and compare their sizes.
If the value in `u` is less than or equal to the value in `l` then print `Truth` to the console.

> **Error**

The IDE (xcode 9.1) keeps giving me this error

`Redefinition of u`

**HOW do I correct this?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int u, l;
    cout << "Enter value : \n";
    cin >> u;
    cout << "Enter next value : \n";
    cin >>  l;
    if (u<=l) {
        cout << "Truth";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have a (possibly global) variable named `u` elsewhere?

Comment: No repro with gcc and clang. Please provide more detailed information about your environment.

Comment: No repro with Visual C++ either.

Comment: Errors like this often give some info on where the first definition is.

Comment: @Fureeish This is exactly the error I had.

Answer (score 1):

it should be no problem for the code
try to create a new project again, maybe u define 'u' at somewhere els

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that I had a global `u` else in the code. I removed it.

Comment: So, the code you posted was not the code that had the problem. Don't do that.

Comment: @Pete Becker Apologies